# ERC721 Contract: 1 ether = 1 token for network deployed on?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, ether

I am new to Solidity and looking over an ERC721 NFT contract.

I see in the code they set variables of prices to things like `uint256 public MINT_PRICE = 1.5 ether;`.

Does this mean that the price would be 1.5 of AVAX if were deploying this contract onto the Avalanche network whose base token is AVAX?

Comment: I forgot to mention that as long as tokens have same decimals, most of them are 18, they are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calculations are done in the base units for a token.

```
   uint256 public MINT_PRICE = 1.5 avax;
```

People uses "ether" for  placeholder

Note that gas fees are always paid in "ether" if your contract is on ethereum.

Comment: Got it, thanks. IIUC, is handling of payment for NFT done somewhere else outside of the ERC721 solidity contract then?

Comment: nft is erc721 contract. gas fees are paid in ether. If you are using oracle services, you are paying oracle service in currency that they accept